# Write to file and keep the same formatting as the terminal does with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am working with a file that has numbers and letters in it. I managed to remove the letters with regexps, but when I try to output the file with just the numbers in using:

```
matchIt = File.open('numbers.txt', 'a') {|f| f.write(string[i]) }
```

they appear attached together like this:

```
1613714531731413747
```

When I run a ruby script from the terminal, I normally type:

```
ruby script.rb > numbers.txt
```

which would then format the numbers downward:

```
1

2

3

4

5
```

Can I do the same thing with ruby using the command I have above?

Comment: Your regexp is probably dropping the newline character that is present on each of your input strings.  Can you post the regexp that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to print a new line for each number, just use `f.puts` instead of `f.write`.